# win10 Remote Desktop Connect audio recording devices disappear

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop

before I RDP into my laptop, the audio devices tab looks like this:[image]

But when I use the Remote Desktop Connection Manager program on my win10 desktop, and connect to the laptop, the recording devices suddenly all disappear:[image]

I tried this answer: [Windows 10 Remote Desktop sound/drive redirection not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1213547/windows-10-remote-desktop-sound-drive-redirection-not-working/1214786#1214786)

And set the service to automatic on both machines, but devices still all disappear when i connect.